# how to create xml file for izpack?

Tags: java, xml, izpack

I want to create my java application into a software. Then make it as an installer(setup). Also i made the java application into an executable jar. I am using IzPack for create installer. But i dont know create xml file for IzPack to add in it. If anybody know means, send me the procedure with example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hello 
In the link below you will find a nice help about izpack installer.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89

Link below contains a detailed pdf to make installer with izpack.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?attachment_id=112

cheers

Imran tariq

Answer (score 0):

You have to study the documentation comes along with IZpack and it also have sample files read that.

Comment: Some of the topics covered in documentation is not very well explained. And declaring variable as described in documentation is not working. But it is a good start for understanding Izpack. You can see my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598073/izpack-validator-doesnt-work) and my answer(Nobody answered my question :( I have discovered a way around).